# Why don't backbone localStorage keys seem accessible?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

... through the console.

Here is a [backbone test application.](http://localtodos.com/)

If I open up the console in Firefox will auto-fill this value:

```
localStorage.todos-backbone
```

I get an error as such:

```
backbone is not defined
```

which makes me think that it is parsing the `-` that backbone uses to create the key.

Comment: wonder why they did not just use an underscore?

Comment: @user3293082 Because they didn't want to? I use localStorage keys of the form `USERID+".something"` all the time.

Comment: principles.  design descions.

Answer (score 3):

Uhm... hm.

```
localStorage['todos-backbone'];
```

Otherwise the `-` is a minus sign and it's looking for a variable called `backbone` to subtract from `localStorage.todos` (which also doesn't exist)